# change color BorderSide when switching to dark theme

Tags: flutter, dart

The code in the photo is responsible for building the widget. The red line is responsible for constructing the line that underlines the inscription "Location information"

[image]
[image]

With a white theme, this line is black. Can you tell me how can I make it white when the application theme switches to dark?

```
   .....
    class MyThemes {
      static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(),
        listTileTheme: ListTileThemeData(iconColor: Colors.white,),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          subtitle2: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
          );
  ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `color` on `BorderSide`

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  border: Border(
    bottom: BorderSide(
      color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
          ? Colors.white
          : Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
),
```

You can also check `Text`'s `decoration` and instead using `Theme.of(context).brightness` you can use your theme data.

Comment: You are a great programmer :) Thank you very much, this is not the first time you help

Comment: glad to help you out. You check more about [`Border`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Border-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default `Border` draw black color if no color value is provided.

You can use `color` property in `BorderSide` constructor to change the border color.

In your case, you can use the color from theme like this..

```dart
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      width: 1.0,
                      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.color
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text('Location Information'),
              )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this case the color of the entire container changes. But I would like to change the color of only the specified line. Can this be done somehow?

Comment: My bad. I misplaced the border property outside the `BorderSide` as per the above answer.